# Serial communication with Arduino uno using python only works one line at a time

Tags: python, arduino

I'm trying to use an Arduino Uno to control a simple relay switch. When it receives the serial command "SET STATE ON", pin 2 should go high. for "SET STATE OFF", it should go low. For "GET STATE" it should return either a 0 or 1.

If I try control the arduino one line at a time, it works exactly as expected. But if I write a script using the exact same lines, it doesn't work.

arduino code:

```
int OUTPUT_PIN=2;
volatile int val = LOW;
String incomingCommand;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(OUTPUT_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(OUTPUT_PIN, LOW);
  val = LOW;
}

void loop() {
  // Check if any data is available on serial:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    //read latest serial command as string
    incomingCommand = Serial.readString();
    
    // turn on dispenser
    if (incomingCommand == "SET STATE ON") {
      digitalWrite(OUTPUT_PIN, HIGH);
      val = HIGH;
      
    }
    // return state of dispenser (1 for on, 0 for off)
    else if (incomingCommand == "GET STATE") {
      Serial.print(val, DEC);
    }
    // for any other command, turn off
    else {
      digitalWrite(OUTPUT_PIN, LOW);
      val = LOW;
    }
  }
  
}
```

Python Code

```
import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial('COM6', baudrate=9600)

ser.write(b'SET STATE ON')

ser.write(b'GET STATE')

print(ser.read_all())
```

The output should be either b'0', or b'1', but I consistently receive no output when executing the script. When I run it one line at a time in a terminal, I receive b'1', as I should, and pin 2 is set to high.

I've already tried adding delays between lines, but it the result is the same. Any help with this issue owuld be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You are sending `SET STATE ONGET STATE` to the Arduino, which doesn't match either defined command.  You need to use `Serial.readStringUntil()` to allow the inputs to be explicitly terminated by a delimiter character (typically `'\n'`), rather than having to wait a full second for a timeout to occur, and add that delimiter to the commands you're sending from Python.

Answer (score 0):

You read what could be a single byte and test against a full string.

```
void loop()
{
    // ...

    if (Serial.available() > 0) {  // at 9600 bauds, this could be true after
                                   // 1 ms (a long time) since ONE character
                                   // will be available, there is no guarantee
                                   // that you will receive a full command
                                   // You could also get two commands 'glued' together.

        incomingCommand = Serial.readString();   // you read 1 byte
  
        if (incomingCommand == "SET STATE ON") {  // this is always false, 
                                                  // except (maybe) on startup

    // ...
}
```

If you want to test for the whole string, you first need to store the input string in an appropriate buffer.  You also need to add a termination character to your commands, so the receiving side can synchronize correctly with the sending side.  A new line character '\n' or a combination of carriage return and line feed "\r\n" is customary for text interfaces like yours.

Example:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------
// Types

// Hint: this should be tucked away in its own header file.

// loads a line of command from Serial into a buffer.
struct command_loader
{
  static constexpr int CMDBUF_SIZE = 16;  // "SET STATE OFF" + crlf + '\0' is 13 + 2 + 1 = 16 bytes long
  char buffer_[CMDBUF_SIZE];
  int next_char_ = 0;
  bool ready_    = false;

  // ------------------------------------------------------
  // reads bytes from serial and stores command in buffer
  // returns: true if a command has been received in full
  bool read_from_serial()
  {
    if (ready())  // clear previous command
      reset();

    while (!ready() && Serial.available() > 0)
    {
      char c = (char)Serial.read();

      switch (c)
      {
        case '\r':
        case '\n':
          ready_ = (next_char_ != 0); // we have a non empty line!
          buffer_[next_char_] = '\0'; // null terminate string
          break;

        default:
          if (next_char_ >= CMDBUF_SIZE - 1)
          {
            Serial.println("ERROR: CMD Buffer overflow!!!");
            reset();
          }
          buffer_[next_char_++] = c;
          break;
      }
    }
    return ready();
  }

  // ------------------------------------------------------
  // clears input buffer
  void reset()
  {
    ready_ = false;
    next_char_ = 0;
  }

  // ------------------------------------------------------
  // checks if command line available
  bool ready() const 
  {
    return ready_;
  }

  // ------------------------------------------------------
  // compares to command
  bool operator==(const char* s) const
  {
    return ready() && (strcmp(buffer_, s) == 0);
  }

  // ------------------------------------------------------
  // converts to const char* for printing
  operator const char* () const
  {
    return buffer_;
  }
};

// ------------------------------------------------------
// Data

command_loader input_command;

// ------------------------------------------------------

void setup()
{
  // ....

  input_command.reset();   // making sure never hurts.
}

// ------------------------------------------------------

void loop()
{
  if (input_command.read_from_serial())
  {
    Serial.print("Got: "); Serial.println(input_command);

    if (input_command == "SET STATE ON")
    {
      // ...
    }
    else if (input_command == "SET STATE OFF")
    {
      // ...
    }
    else if (input_command == "GET STATE")
    {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```